# Query with an array as parameter, how to convert to GoLang mgo?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mgo

I have the following query:

```
db.getCollection('spawnlocations').find({
    'location': {
        '$geoWithin': {
            '$center': [[-73.94075, 40.789138], 5000]
        }
    }, 
    "expirationtimems": { "$gte": 1234567890 }, 
    "_id": { "$gte": "2a920240836c40d8b374203a798a27fa.16" }
}).sort({"_id":1}).limit(50)
```

I am trying to convert the query to mgo using `bson.M` but I'm having a hard time with the array part of it.

I thought this would work, but of course it doesn't

```
    q = bson.M{
        "location": bson.M{
            "$geoWithin": bson.M{
                "$center": [
                    j.Location.Coordinates,
                    5000
                ],
            },
        },
        "expirationtimems": bson.M{
            "$gte": time.Now().Unix() * 1000,
        },
        "_id": bson.M{
            "$gt": p,
        },
    }
```

Comment: `"$center": interface[]{interface[]{-73.94075,40.789138}, 5000}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
"$center": []interface{}{j.Location.Coordinates, 5000}
```

This line is probably an error:

```
 time.Now().Unix() * 1000
```

Did you want `+ 1000`?